# Drawing Shadow of an object in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw one circle and a character with shadow on a canvas in a HTML page while loading the page and recreate the image on a button click. I am using this code:

```
window.onload = function() {

    draw();
};

function draw(){

var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
var width = c.width;
var height = c.height;

//DRAW A CIRCLE
var centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width));
var centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height));
var radius = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
var color = '#f11';
ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

//DRAW A CHARACTER WITH SHADOW
var c = "S";
ctx.font = "300% Verdana";
ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
ctx.shadowColor = "black";
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 20;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 20;
ctx.fillStyle = "#111";
ctx.fillText(c, 10, 90);
}
```

In HTML I am calling draw function onclick() event of a button named Refresh.
For the first time it is giving desired output by drawing one circle and a character with shadow. As I click on the Refresh button it is drawing both the objects with shadow. I dont want to draw shadow of the circle. Can anyone please tell me the mistake I'm doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the [CanvasRenderingContext2D.save()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) method :

```js
window.onload = function() {

    draw();
};
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener('click', draw);

function draw(){

var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
var width = c.width;
var height = c.height;

//DRAW A CIRCLE
var centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width));
var centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height));
var radius = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
var color = '#f11';
ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

//DRAW A CHARACTER WITH SHADOW
//save the actual context
  ctx.save();
var c = "S";
ctx.font = "300% Verdana";
ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
ctx.shadowColor = "black";
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 20;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 20;
ctx.fillStyle = "#111";
ctx.fillText(c, 10, 90);
  //restore it 
ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```